# Dask iloc workaround?

Tags: dask, dask-dataframe

I'd like to index into a Dask dataframe -- like iloc in Pandas, but I know that this is not possible.

Would the following be an okay workaround? Are there potential drawbacks?

```
df.reset_index(drop=True)
df['column'].loc[index]
```

I'm guessing there must be some drawback to this -- otherwise, why isn't this the implementation for iloc in Dask?

Comment: Can you elaborate as to what you're trying to accomplish? May help people provide input to a possible solution.

Comment: @joeb I just want to get the i'th index of a column... I don't know what to explain beyond this?

Comment: Could you show us an example of how you'd accomplish this with just `pandas`? Including the sample data please.